# relational data in parse.com classes

Tags: parse-platform

I have two tables (Classes):

1. StudentInformation: with columns METNumber, address, grade, name, school
2. Behaviour15Min :    with columns METNumber, onTaskMinutes, percentOnTask, percentOffTask

both of these tables obviously also hold the autogenerated objectId, createdAt, and updatedAt columns

Not sure how to figure out relations in this. What I would like to do is have my last activity receive the METNumber from the previous activity, and query the Classes given the METNumber. Problem is, METNumber is only unique in the StudentInformation Class.

I tried to do a query ordered by date created, but I always ended up with the second newest object instead of the newest.... So that doesn't work. Can't figure out a way to get the autogenerated objectId, because I am not supplying it, it is being generated serverside.

THen I tried using their model for relations, but when I do (say I get my test scores, which completely populate every column in Behaviour15Min, and add METNum to the Student Information Class using their model), I just end up with an entry on my SI Class that has all empty columns except for METNumber. And then that isn't unique.

Bottom line: how the heck do I query info out of two tables/Classes?

Comment: Questions first: 
* I assume you want sample code. Which platform is this being written in?
* Is an activity a behavior? If so, do a pointer to the SI, not a relation. You can then query the SI doc for the METNumber. I say this - not knowing from what you write, what is 1:1, 1:M, M:M if that matters at all. I usually think it does.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the methods MatcheQuery between two PFQuery? Try to see this example ... Through this you can create two queries and merge them together to PFObject fat meal may delay data from a different (and therefore from a different class ...) Try to see and let me know

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS